# To_Char and T_Number alternate in SQL Server for formatting

Tags: sql-server, oracle, casting, formatting, to-char

What is the SQL Server alternate of

> To_CHAR([Column_Name], -987654321)
>
> To_Number([Column_Name],'999999999D99999900')

?
Also,
What I can predict from the syntax is that they both are being used for formatting. Then what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) in Sql Server is done like this:

```
CAST([column] AS CHAR([required length]))
CAST([column] AS [whatever numeric type you want])
```

Afterwards you can use the [`FORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh213505.aspx) function **if you are using Sql Server 2012** or higher.

```
FORMAT([value], [format])
```

In your case, I would try this:

```
FORMAT(CAST([column] AS CHAR([required length])), '-987654321')
FORMAT(CAST([column] AS [whatever numeric type you want]), '000000000.000000##')
```

Although I don't quite understand what your formatting strategy is here, especially for your `CHAR` casting... :)

Prior to Sql Server 2012 formatting values is awkward, at best. The good news is that if you know some C# you could expose the powerful .NET Framework formatting mechanism as a [Sql User Defined Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) mapped to a [assembly running on SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/104406/). From there you could very easily make an equivalent of the SQL2012 FORMAT function. This will work with Sql Server 2005 and 2008.

Comment: I don't think I can use CAST([Column] AS Char(-987654321)) in SQL Server.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite Indeed you can't. Casting and formatting in SQL Server doesn't come together.